# Get list of terms of current taxonomy archive for another taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have a Custom Post Type named 'Real estate' which has (amongst others) two different taxonomies:

- 'Purpose' (hierarchical; terms used are 'Living', 'Working' and 'Holidays') and
- 'Location' (non-hierarchical; e.g. 'London', 'Berlin', 'Paris').

For a search form on the 'Living' taxonomy archive I would need a list of all 'Location' terms associated with posts in the 'Living' taxnonomy term archive in order to give it back in the search form through a select.
How can I, best as a list of comma separated values for an array, get all the terms for 'Location' used in the 'Living' term archive?

Comment: I'm doing something extremely similar to this at the moment. I don't feel I can write conclusively enough to "answer", but I'm using the WP_Query class with the tax_query parameter to query posts which belong in both taxonomies/terms/whatever you need. 

As this appears to be a lot of queries (potentially) I've been reading up on caching the query using transients. A similar solutions might work for you?

Comment: Hey Dan, doesn't sound as much fun as I thought - I actually believed it would be a no-brainer three-lines code solution that I just did not find. Do I really have to query all posts of tax term in order to get all values for another taxonomy? I just need it in a list like `array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');` - which might just sound easier than it actually is ;). Thank you so far!!

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for the names/IDs of terms in the Location taxonomy, which are associated with posts in the Purpose->living term? If so, I believe I did this by looping through each term in the second tax (Location), trying to find one post which was present both there AND in your first tax/term. I agree, it sounds bloated - I researched a better solution but never found one. Maybe someone a little more skilled that me can help!

Comment: Yes, exactly how you describe it. I would have believed that it would be easy to accomplish with get_term_by in a way, but I got stuck in not really knowing what I was doing since I am more of a designer than a (PHP) coder. Names or IDs or slugs are fine alike, so it's more like the way of pulling the data and formatting it appropriately, so I won't be shown with places to pick that are not there houses filed under 'Living' ;).

Comment: I wrote a 120 lines function that do that in a flexible, reusable way. https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/11190603

Comment: Hi G.M., thanks a bunch. Can you elaborate on how to use it? I actually don't really see what I am supposed to do with it ;). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: As far as I am able to understand the code, it rather puts out a list of posts or something belonging to two terms of different taxonomies. What I just need is an array (as a comma separated list [no html]) of terms used from one taxonomy ('Location') in another taxonomy term's archive - is that what the function does?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I've got something for you! As you know, I've had the same issue, and when I was looping through each taxonomy I found that I was generating between 25-35 queries, which is crazy! So I decided to have a go at some MySQL on the term relationships table to see if there was a faster was to query the data.

With some help from a great developer I know (Mac McDonald http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/ ), I've made a function which makes one request and returns and array of term IDs in the "other" taxonomy. You can have to prepare the term IDs to query against first, like this;

//the taxonomy we want to check terms for
    $opposite_taxonomy_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

```
//new array, with current term id, very important!
$sibling_term_ids = array( $this_term->term_id );

foreach( $opposite_taxonomy_terms as $term )
{
    //collect all ids, ready to build the MySQL query
    $sibling_term_ids[] = $term->term_id;

}

$imploded = implode(', ', $sibling_term_ids );

$results = rd_get_opposite_terms( $imploded, $this_term->term_id );
```

I'm getting the terms I wish to "check" for, and then adding them to an array which must contain the main term ID you're querying against. I then implode this to get a comma separated list for the MySQL query. That's found in the `rd_get_opposite_terms()` function;

```
function rd_get_opposite_terms( $imploded = array(), $current_term_id = FALSE )
{
    if( empty( $imploded ) || ! $current_term_id )
        return FALSE;

    global $wpdb;

    //perform a query to find terms that have posts in both the $current_term_id (from one taxonomy) and terms in $imploded (term IDs from another taxonomy). Returns IDs as an array.
    return $wpdb->get_col( 'SELECT tr1.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships tr1 WHERE tr1.term_taxonomy_id IN ( ' . $imploded . ' ) AND tr1.object_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships tr2 WHERE tr2.term_taxonomy_id = ' . $current_term_id . ' ) GROUP BY tr1.term_taxonomy_id' );
}
```

I admit, this is near the top end of my development ability at this point in time, but I think it's a much better solution than what I originally had, and I hope it helps you too!

Comment: Still not having gotten my head around to try it out, but your code is still puzzling me a bit. I am still not really sure as how to use it. I need a variable that holds the array in a custom query for a WP search form, like so:

Comment: Update: Sorry for the long wait, didn't have enough time to get my head around to try it out, but your code is still puzzling me a bit. I am still not really sure as how to use it. I need a variable that holds the array in a custom query for a WP search form, like so:
`'terms' => array('value1', 'value2', 'value3')`
I got everything working, except for the right values from the desired term :D. I declare the opposite term ( 'location' ) as taxonomy via $opposite_taxonomy_terms. However, what variable do I hold to put out the array?

Comment: Okay, I think I see through, though it doesn't throw out what I need. 
1. I am sitting in my 'Purpose' term archive.
2. I define `$opposite_taxonomy_terms = get_terms( 'location' );`
3. I use
`return $wpdb->get_col( 'SELECT tr1.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships tr1 WHERE tr1.term_taxonomy_id IN ( ' . $imploded . ' ) AND tr1.object_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships tr2 WHERE tr2.term_taxonomy_id = ' . $current_term_id . ' ) GROUP BY tr1.term_taxonomy_id' )?>` to output the array, but all it shows is the word 'Array'. 

I am surely missing out on something?

Comment: Have you done a `print_r`? It's supposed to return an array of IDs you can use, but you need to see what IDs are in the array first to check if it's working.

Comment: Hey there, how exactly? print_r $wpdb->get_col('... etc.?

Comment: `print_r( $results );`

Comment: Yeah, it prints out exactly nothing, I am afraid (and I know how to put it into the template, in case you wonder :D).

Comment: In that case, the only way I could help any more is if I can see your code. Perhaps you could edit the original post with the code I posted in the answer so I can see what's going on.

Comment: Hey there, sorry for not getting back for so long, I was on vacations plus dug into other projects. Thank you so much so far for helping me!
I don't know what part you need exactly, so I pasted you the whole template (taxonomy.php) I had created here: http://pastebin.com/F6SnP6Us . If you would need anything else, please let me know! The underlying script is WP Advanced Search (http://wpadvancedsearch.com/) which I used here. Thanks in advance again!
Edit: Location is 'objektort', Purpose is 'objektkategorie', the given template is used for the 'objektkategorie' terms.

Comment: And please ignore everything below line 101 ;).